# Route 53 "Too Many Redirects" but access from ELB works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

- I have an EC2 running pgadmin.
- There's a target group pointing to it on port 80.
- The TG is listening on port 443 but HTTP so it can redirect to the
  EC2 on port 80. *(I previously had it 443 and HTTPs but read online
  that SSL termination should be here)*
- There's an ELB listening on 443 and pointing to the TG.

If I go to the URL of the ELB I **can successfully access pgadmin**, although obviously the browser shows a certificate error because the URL isn't the one in the ACM cert associated with the ELB.

I have R53 domain with an alias to the ELB, which matches the ACM cert, but when I go to this URL I get 'too many redirects' in the browser.

Not sure where the config could be wrong, especially as it works from the ELB just not the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly typical in case of SSL termination is that the back-end server/service will perceive that as: *"the end-user is connected over a clear text protocol"* , in other words over plain http.

It will then helpfully try to "resolve that security risk" by redirecting the user to HTTPS.

```
 ------                  ---------------                -------------------
| USER  | ===> HTTP ==> | Load balancer | ==> HTTP ==> | Redirect to HTTPS | 
 ------                  ---------------                -------------------

 ------                   -----------------                -------------------
| USER  | ===> HTTPS ==> | SSL termination | ==> HTTP ==> | Redirect to HTTPS | 
 ------                   -----------------                -------------------
```

User makes a new request (they were already using HTTPS, but a redirect is a redirect) but they will again be redirected:

```
 ------                   -----------------                -------------------
| USER  | ===> HTTPS ==> | SSL termination | ==> HTTP ==> | Redirect to HTTPS | 
 ------                   -----------------                -------------------
```

And then repeat that again and again.

The usual solution is to optionally re-configure the SSL termination point to make HTTPS requests to the back-end server, and remove the redirect to HTTPS functionality from the back-end server and move that to Load Balancer.

```
 ------                  -------------------  
| USER  | ===> HTTP ==> | Load balancer     | 
 ------                 | Redirect to HTTPS |      
                         -------------------

 ------                   -----------------                   ---------
| USER  | ===> HTTPS ==> | SSL termination | ==> HTTP(S) ==> | Respond | 
 ------                   -----------------                   ---------
```